# Sitecore Workbox, display item field for name?

Tags: sitecore

By default Sitecore workbox displays the item name, I want to display the "Title" field (Custom field). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar requirement where a client needed the Workbox to display the item's 'path' instead of it's name. The problem was that many of their items shared the same name - making it difficult to distinguish between items.

Unfortunately, this change required us to make a custom implementation of the Sitecore WorkboxForm class. I would normally not recommend modifying Sitecore like this, but for something as important as the Workbox, it may be worth the hassle.

1. In the root of your Sitecore website, locate the following file:

   `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Workbox\Workbox.xml`
2. Change the CodeBeside to point to your custom implementation of the WorkboxForm class. The default class is located under the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm` namespace in the `Sitecore.Client` assembly. You can essentially open Sitecore's class in Reflector and copy everything into your new class.
3. In the private **CreateItem()** method, change the following line to use the item's title (I used item.Paths.ContentPath):

   `webControl["Header"] = item["Your Title"];`

Comment: Something else to consider is that you should also be able to implement this using the override folder to avoid the need to change core Sitecore files. If you keep the same name for the xml and place it in /sitecore/shell/override the system will use this application instead of the default meaning you are less likely to have issues during an upgrade.