# Sitecore Workbox - Modify "Open" to open up the content editor item in a new browser tab

Tags: sitecore

In the Workbox we have “Open” and “Preview” functionality.
Is it possible to modify the “Open” functionality to open the content editor item in a new browser tab, rather than displaying the “Content Editor” in a pop-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Appconfig/Commands.config you can find commands and classes related to them.
I have reflected some commands like preview, open and understood what's going on internally.

e.g. name="item:open" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ContentEditor.OpenItem,Sitecore.Kernel"

And I have overridded the "Open" mwthod in the workbox as follows to open the content editor item in the new tab,

```
...
UrlString urlString = new UrlString("/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor");

        urlString.Append("id", id);
        urlString.Append("vs", version);
        urlString.Append("ro", sectionId);
        urlString.Append("la", language);
        urlString.Append("fo", id);

        SheerResponse.Eval("window.open('" + (object)urlString + "', '_blank')");
...
```

It works!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

That's possible: 
First, find out what code is used for the workbox. This can be done by opening the Workbox.xml (located in webroot/sitecore/shell/Applications/Workbox) file.
You'll see something like

```
<CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

By using Reflector on the WorkboxForm class I can see that the following happens when you click 'Open' in workbox:

```
webControl["Click"] = string.Concat(new object[] { "Open(\"", item.ID, "\", \"", item.Language, "\", \"", item.Version, "\")" });
```

So you'll need to create your own version of a WorkboxForm, inheriting Sitecore's WorkboxForm class and override the Open method, something like so:

```
protected new void Open(string id, string language, string version)
{
// Your code goes here
}
```

In Workbox.xml, change the CodeBeside to point to your new class.

For more information on custom functionality in the Workbox, I can recommend reading through [this](http://blog.navigationarts.com/customizing-the-sitecore-workbox/) article, which has a lot of detail in it, also on other methods in the Workbox.
There's also another useful [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645368/sitecore-workbox-display-item-field-for-name) on StackOverflow already. The comment on the accepted answer points out you can put your Workbox.xml file into /sitecore/shell/override.

Please note that this is based on Sitecore 6.5 update 5, it might differ a bit in other versions.

Comment: HI, Thanks Trayek. I already have a custom workbox module. Can you help me with the implementation inside the Open method? I have no idea how to open the content editor in a new tab.

Comment: Have a read through this: http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/open-content-editor-on-specific-item.html
Obviously you'll need to go for the first option, as the second opens a new Sitecore application (the way it does now as well)

I don't think you need the sc_content and la parameters - I think if you don't provide them it'll use the DB and language you are currently in (you'll need to confirm that of course).