# Sitecore workbox change sort order

Tags: sitecore

By default Sitecore workbox displays the Item name, and sort the item list by Item name.

In one of my [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645368/sitecore-workbox-display-item-field-for-name) regarding this I managed to change the item name to a custom field.

Now I need to sort workbox by this field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying [Sitecore workbox modifications](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/get-your-workflow-in-order/), I came across with following solution.

Step 1 - Modify the GetItems method as follows,

```
    private DataUri[] GetItems(WorkflowState state, IWorkflow workflow)
    {  
        if (workflow != null)
        {
            var items = workflow.GetItems(state.StateID);                
            Array.Sort(items, new Comparison<DataUri>(CompareDataUri));
            return items;
        }
        return new DataUri[] { };
    }
```

Here comes the "CompareDataUri" method,

```
    private int CompareDataUri(DataUri x, DataUri y)
    {
        //Custom method written to compare two values - Dhanuka
        Item itemX = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(x);
        Item itemY = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(y);

        string m_sortField = "__Updated";
        bool m_descSort = false;

        var res = 0;

        res = string.Compare(itemX[m_sortField], itemY[m_sortField]);

        if (m_descSort)
        {
            if (res > 0)
                return -1;
            if (res < 0)
                return 1;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

This approach is optimized for performance.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you already have your own implementation of the `WorkboxForm` as described in the post you linked in your question, you need to change the code of the `DisplayState` method.

The `DataUri[] items` inflow parameter of this method gives you the list of all items which are in given state of the workflows. You need to retrieve all the **Sitecore** items from this parameter and sort them:

```
DataUri[] items = new DataUri[0];
List<Item> sitecoreItems = items
    .Select(uri => Context.ContentDatabase.Items[uri])
    .OrderBy(item => item["YourCustomField"])
    .ToList();
```

And use the new list for selecting the current page items. This solution is not optimized for the performance - you need to get every item in given state from database so you can access the custom field.